# Add all .css files to precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

I want to include all css files to precompile. Right now Im using @import to include other css into application.css. But I want to load specific css file according to the controller with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

It gave me an error, telling me to add the css to the precompiler. Say I add this to config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages.css )
```

Now it works, but only for that particular controller. I could just go manually add each css file for each controllers. It will work like that, but there must be a better way.

Im using bootstrap so I cant use:

```
*= require_
```

I have tried both (not at the same time):

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = %w( *.css *.js)
```

but now I got this error:

```
Undefined variable: "$alert-padding-y".
```

Which I guess comes from bootstrap. But it was working before I try to add files to precompile.

=====

Edit: I tried what [Daniel Westendorf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518336/daniel-westendorf) post. Putting this code in the assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = []
Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "**", "*.css")].each do |file|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << file
end
```

But I got this error:

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

I tried to fix it by adding both the css and js (it asked for it later):

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css application.js )
```

But I still ended up with the same error anyway:

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

Answer (score 1):

This is generally against the better conventions of the web. One larger, cached, network request will perform better for you than many smaller, individual, network requests.

You could, however, find all the `.css` files in your assets directory, and add each one to the precompile array. Something like:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = []
Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "**", "*.css")].each do |file|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << file
end
```

Comment: Right. Just add a class to the html or body element and use it in your stylesheets / js. Depending on different files to loaded is outdated and does not work well with turbolinks.

Comment: I intended on having each page load at most 2 css. One global and another one specific to that controller. If this isnt good practice Im willing to do it the correct way. That would be put all css into one file, even if some stylings are not used?

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but when I tried your method I got error.

Trying to post in comment is kinda weird, I will edit the main post.

Comment: Yes, you should include them all in one file, even if they aren't used on that page, because the browser will cache the one large style sheet and not need to download it again on the other pages which do use the other styles. Network requests are more expensive than file size, in most cases.

Comment: As for my code, it assumes your files end in .css, not .scss, .less, or other.

Comment: I use SCSS and coffee. I will try to adjust your code then. ps: why dont I get notification for your comment here? I had to manually check to see that you have answered.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code. It works perfectly fine for me.

Add this code in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
# for css files
Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "**", "*.css")].each do |file|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << file
end

# for js files
Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "**", "*.js")].each do |file|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << file
end
```